# How to change the text color of a Telerik ASP.NET grid

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("Grid_onDataBinding"))
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Grid_onDataBinding(e){
        //handling code
    }
</script>
```

I need to change the color of text in each column in the `databind` event. How can I access the `Rowdata` by JavaScript in a Telerik Grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to handle RowDataBound event which is fired when the row is bound. This would then give you access to the row (TR).

```
...
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("Grid_onRowDataBound"))

function Grid_onRowDataBound(e) {
    var row = e.row;
    var dataItem = e.dataItem;

    row.className = "your-class-name";
    // Can also use row.cells
    // row.cells[1].innerHTML = "<span class='class-name'>" + dataItem.text + "</strong>";
}
```

Styles

```
tr.your-class-name {
    color: red;
}
```